# What is the purpose of this underline in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, underline

I'm getting an underline under seemingly random sections of text in Sublime Text. Could anyone tell me what is causing this?

[image: screenshot of some underlined text]

The `div` class underneath is the same structure exactly but doesn't seem to have the underline, if I randomly type letters some of the combinations will be underlined and others won't. I assume this is Sublime trying to tell me something?

Comment: What plugins do you have installed? Look in `Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings` for a list.

Comment: I've got Emmet, which seems to usually be the cause of these problems. Other than that nothing of note, two plugins to show colour, sass, sublime tutor and something called PyV8.

Comment: `PyV8` is one of `Emmet`'s dependencies. To fully blame the underlining on Emmet, simply disable it by adding it to the `"ignored_packages"` key in your user settings. I don't use Emmet much nowadays, but I recall seeing a notice recently that a new version has been released that has some breaking changes with previous versions, so perhaps there's some new setting that's causing this behavior.

Comment: It may also be worth changing your `color_scheme` - at least trying a few different colour schemes. I've sometimes found it necessary to make minor modifications to mine.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm also experiencing this. Just randomly started. I also have emmet and color picker

Comment: It wasn’t solved but it just seems to go away after a while so I chose to ignore it, not helpful but hopefully we may see an answer sometime soon!

Comment: Tks for the suggestion @MattDMo I had this issue and it was Emmet. Not fixed yet but good to know via temporary `ignored_packages` setting.